# Scraping data from Twitch

Tags: javascript, html, r, phantomjs, twitch

I am trying to find out how many Followers each game on Twitch has. Unfortunately, this information is not available from the Twitch API. When I go to any game (like [Mortal Kombat 11](https://www.twitch.tv/directory/game/Mortal%20Kombat%2011)) I can see "115,175 Followers · 199,041 Viewers". However, when I go to "View Source", this information is not there. I have tried using phantomjs to open the site, but so far I have not been able to figure out how to have that part render.

How can I scrape the number of Followers and Viewers for a given game on Twitch?

(Solutions in R preferred but not mandatory)

Comment: Hey, are you using python?

Comment: Sure, Python would also be great

Comment: Check out this similar question. [Somewhat similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31096293/how-to-get-the-name-of-a-streamer-on-twitch-by-scraping-certain-content-pages)

Comment: I think i found solution for you :) Answered already

Answer (score 1):

I have created a web **scraper** months ago using [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) and [cheerio](https://cheerio.js.org/).

You can get the whole HTML page with axios with a get request and then with cheerio start looking for the information that you want in this case the followers, cheerio is like a server-side jquery.

A small example:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import cheerio from 'cheerio';
import _ from 'lodash';

async function getStats () {
  const html = await axios.get('http://www.espn.com/nba/team/_/name/ny');
  const $ = cheerio.load(html.data);
  const wonLooseRatio = $('.ClubhouseHeader__Record').children().first().text().trim();
  
  console.log(wonLooseRatio); // 17-65
}
```

the image illustrates the information that in **scraping**.

[image: the image illustrates the information that in scraping.]

also, keep in mind that some sites consider web scraping illegal or against their policies, make sure you read twitch terms and conditions, the example above is just educative purposes.

Hope it helps.